# Cannot get string param in POST method from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have POST method like this

```
    public void PostMethod([FromBody]string param)
    {
        var test = param;
    }
```

And simple JS script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8101/sd/Localization/PostMethod',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        param: 'test'
    }
});
</script>
```

Ot work great. Ajax call is invoking the method BUT the param is null :/ always. I don`t know why. I can't get it running. Can someone pls help me and show me the correct direction ?

// update

too check something i`ve created new project to be sure that i didn't break something. Even in new project in default config I always get null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `param` is a *simple type*, so to make it work for simple type, you just:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://localhost:8101/sd/Localization/PostMethod', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data:  {"" : 'test' } 
    } 
}); 
</script>
```

If you still want to make POST request like yours, define you own strong type model:

```
class YourModel
{
    public string Param {get; set;}
}
```

So your action:

```
public void PostMethod(YourModel param)   
{   
    var test = param;   
}
```

Or use `JObject`:

```
public void PostMethod(JObject param)   
{   
    var test = param;   
}
```

More information:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1

Comment: Thank you for help. I'm testing in on simple type. What if I want to use a more complex type. What do I need to change ? The second thing I'll be trying to achive is sending this from C# not with JS

Comment: ok last question. Do you know some good samples of sending same post request but with c# ?

Comment: @Fixus: You should ask another question instead of using comment, anyway you can use HttpClient for this, lot of questions on stackoverflow. For sample: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/26/asp-net-web-api-and-httpclient-samples.aspx